# Include jQuery, if not included already

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to include the jquery in file, if not included already in the page.
How can I do this?

I wrote this, but it's giving undesired output.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ('undefined' == typeof window.jQuery) {
    // jQuery not present
//  alert("Jquery Unavailable");
<?php echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>'; ?>
} else {
    // jQuery present
    alert("Jquery Available");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787569/best-way-to-avoid-including-stylesheets-external-js-more-than-once-in-a-page

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you cant do that in PHP. Try this instead

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if(typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></'+'script>');
  }

</script>
```

Comment: That style of `onload` hander assignment risks it being over written. Also calling `document.write` after the `onload` event fires will trash the existing document!

Comment: @Sethunath: Neither your's nor mine code is working.
When I execute this in a page, the end after inner </script> is coming on page **'); }**

Comment: [link](http://w3fools.com/#js_howto) they never explain the danger of using document.write

Comment: Using this there is a warning - `A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js, is invoked via document.write. This MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message.See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.`

Answer (score 11):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){
        var oScriptElem = document.createElement("script");
        oScriptElem.type = "text/javascript";
        oScriptElem.src = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js";
        document.head.insertBefore(oScriptElem, document.head.getElementsByTagName("script")[0])
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Many of the other answers place a script tag within a script tag. I like your answer better. My only suggestion would be to not bother checking the typeof jQuery and just compare it to undefined. ``if(jQuery == undefined)``

Comment: Tough undefined might not be undefined if undefined got redefined in some code above. But sure do whatever you think is best.

Answer (score 10):

You could try the below:

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your PHP is running on the server and outputting some text.

The browser then interprets that text as HTML and JavaScript.

You can't run PHP on the server, in a document it has already sent to the browser, in response to logic running in the browser.

You either need to this entirely in JavaScript or, more sanely, sort out your server side logic so you track if jQuery has been included or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with PHP, which i think is better, you can do this

- before you call the load() function create a variable like :

  > var load_script = 'no';
- the load() function takes a optional parameter that you can use to send data to the server. Use it to post the **load_script** variable you created earlier like this

  > $('#receiver_div').load('mypage.html',{'load_script':load_script},function(html){
  >
  > //stuff to do after the page is load
  >
  > })
- Then in the page you are loading, catch the posted value like this

  > $load_script = $_POST('load_script');
- Then you can do a if statement to exclude the script you want like this

> if($load_script != 'no')
>   {
>
> `echo "<script src="jquery.js"></script>"`;
>
> }